How to print lowercase russian letter by its serial number
I have expl3 int variable \l_tmpb_int which contains the serial number of the required lowercase letter.
I would like to insert \int_use:N \l_tmpb_int in required command and get corresponding letter.
I also use polyglossia package, it would be nice if it's implemented using this package functionality.
Serial numbers are like 1, 2, 3 and so on.
Example usage:
\GetLetter{1}
\GetLetter{3}
\GetLetter{5}

Output: а в д
My config for polyglossia:
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands, forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Times New Roman}


It's unclear what you want exactly and what number is in \l_tmpb_int. Is it a Unicode codepoint for a Cyrillic letter (somewhere in the range U+0400-U+04FF)? Or is it a serial number of a letter in some Cyrillic alphabet (Serbian, Bulgarian, Ukraininan etc.)? By the way, I don't think Polyglossia will help much, as it doesn't define letters/alphabets.

Doesn't \symbol{<number>} already do what you want?

@egreg Experimenting with this command, I found that I can produce lowercase russian letters by numbers if I add offset.

If you don’t reveal what you mean by “serial number” how can we help?

@egreg I'm not english native speaker, I didn't understand that you didn't understand) It would be better if you said that earlier. I mean numbers: 1, 2, 3 and so on.

@Intolighter Maybe add an example of what input you imagine and the corresponding output?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Added

@egreg About symbol I was wrong, that were english letters, which I confused to be russian, because of the same spelling.

You could use the \asbuk macro from polyglossia:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands, forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{Times New Roman}
\newcounter{foo}

\newcommand{\GetLetter}[1]{%
  \setcounter{foo}{#1}%
  \asbuk{foo}%
}

\begin{document}

\GetLetter{1}
\GetLetter{3}
\GetLetter{5}

\end{document}


\asbuk intentionally skips some letters (ё and й aren't used in counting items). а б в г д е ё ж з и й к л \dots vs \GetLetter{1} \GetLetter{2} \GetLetter{3} \GetLetter{4} \GetLetter{5} \GetLetter{6} \GetLetter{7} \GetLetter{8} \GetLetter{9} \GetLetter{10} \GetLetter{11} \dots Though may be that's what @Intolighter wants to get.

@SergeiGolovan Thanks for the note, but it's unimportant.

Is there a way to hide a counter?  Like @ in command names. This command will be class command, and I don't want that users have opportunity to collide their counter name with mine.

@Intolighter If you have a new question, please use the "Ask Question" button on the top right.
